# Is there a possibility to assign a value to a tkinter button?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make a battle ship game, where each player puts their different boats on an 10 x 10 field. To know where the boats where placed, I want to change a variable from False to True, if the button was clicked. Also the colour of the button should change to black, but if it is already black it shall change back to grey and also the variable should be false again. 
In my code I defined a class only for the buttons. master should be a frame. The command 'put command' is needed, as I need these buttons for a second frame with another command. bentuzung means whoever is using it (in my case its either 1 or 2).
So I am searching for a way to assign a variable to a button. Also the code should not become too long.

```
from tkinter import *

class buttons():
    def __init__(self, master, benutzung):
        self.button_list = []
        for j in range(10):
            for m in range(10):
                btn = Button(master, text = "     ")
                btn.grid(row = j, column = m)
                self.button_list.append(btn)
        self.put_command(benutzung)
    def put_command(self, benutzung):
        if benutzung == 1:
            for x in self.button_list:
                x.configure(command = lambda bt = x: self.set_ship(bt))
    def set_ship(self, btn):
            btn.configure(bg = "black")
```

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. If you're asking about how to associate a value with a button, we only need one or two buttons. If we can solve the problem with two buttons, we can solve it for 100 buttons. As an aside, you should consider making the buttons in a loop. It will make the code much easier to modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out a solution myself. You can just create a new attribute e.g. 'num' and assign a value to it. Then you can get the value by 'btn.num'.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

class buttons():
    def __init__(self, master, benutzung):
        self.button_list = []

        for j in range(10):
            for m in range(10):

                self.btn = Button(master, text = "     ", bg = "grey")
                self.btn.grid(row = j, column = m)
                self.btn.num = 1
                self.button_list.append(self.btn)
        self.put_command(benutzung)
    def put_command(self, benutzung):
        if benutzung == 1:
            for x in self.button_list:
                x.configure(command = lambda bt = x: self.set_ship(bt))
    def set_ship(self, btn):
        if btn.num == 1:
            btn.configure(bg = "black")
            btn.num = 0
        elif btn.num == 0:
            btn.configure(bg = "grey")
            btn.num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `textvariable` parameter with `IntVar()`.

So your button would be:

```py
num = IntVar()
b = Button(master, text = "str", textvariable = num)
b.pack()
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: When I try this it says 'unknown option: -variable' Edit: It works with 'textvariable'